# Is trying to locate a work that I read in the past an appropriate topic for SF&F.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

There is a particular Sci Fi book that I read when I was in grade school. I checked it out from my little public library long before I was paying any attention to esoteric things like "titles" and "authors." I remember the plot quite well, but I have no idea who wrote it or what it may be called.

Is this kind of a question appropriate for the SF&F.SE community?

If so, I'll open this question properly on the site, and provide all the detail I can remember. But I figured I'd check here first to make sure I don't irritate the regulars. :)

Comment: And here is [an example](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/53128/7885).

Comment: Did you post your question? What is it?

Comment: Yes, I posted two actually. The first: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53055/earthlings-create-and-interact-with-a-pocket-universe-universe-inhabitants-even

Comment: And the second: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53112/humans-travel-to-make-first-contact-with-aliens-aliens-have-caste-system-both

Answer (score 13):

Yes this is on topic. Please see the [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) tag.

Comment: You guys rock. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, story identification questions are on-topic and very common.

Comment: Is there a tag for that, then?

Comment: @CharlieKilian Yes, [story-identification]